# Programmatically altering approval workflow task in separate workflow

Tags: development, workflow, visual-studio, approval-process

Here is my code to programmatically alter the task at hand, the only problem is that the code doesn't alter the "**Outcome**" of the approval task. The Outcome field is blank. "**Task Status**" is Complete, but the Outcome is empty for that task under the workflow status.

Also, under the Task list, the task at hand is 100% complete and set to Completed

```
Hashtable data = new Hashtable();
            data["FormData"] = SPWorkflowStatus.Completed;
            data[SPBuiltInFieldId.Completed] = "TRUE";
            data["Completed"] = "TRUE";
            data[SPBuiltInFieldId.PercentComplete] = 1.0f;
            data["PercentComplete"] = 1.0f;
            data["Status"] = "Completed";
            data[SPBuiltInFieldId.TaskStatus] = SPResource.GetString(new CultureInfo((int)task.Web.Language, false),
                                                                    Strings.WorkflowStatusCompleted, new object[0]);
            data[SPBuiltInFieldId.WorkflowOutcome] = "Approved";
            data["TaskStatus"] = "Approved"; 
            data["ows_FieldName_Comments"] = "Approved by " + user.Name + "\n";
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            SPWorkflowTask.AlterTask(task, data, true);
```

Comment: were you able to get this working?

Comment: No, something leads me to believe it is the build I have that prevents these changes... http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2737435

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working using [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nehajain/archive/2009/05/26/how-to-set-the-outcome-workflow-status-column-to-approved-or-rejected-while-using-the-spworkflowtask-altertask-api-to-alter-the-tasks-programmatically.aspx) and I think you have the incorrect assignment to `data["TaskStatus"]`.

> Set ht["TaskStatus"] = "#"  to set task outcome as “Approved”
>   Set ht["TaskStatus"] = "@" to set task outcome as “Rejected”

```
    // alter the task
    Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
    ht["Status"] = "Complete";
    ht["PercentComplete"] = 1.0f;
    ht["TaskStatus"] = "#";
    SPWorkflowTask.AlterTask((taskedit as SPListItem), ht, true);
```

Comment: tried both ways...

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2013 there is no need to use alter the task.

Directly access the list `Workflow Tasks` and update the item. Following code worked for me:

```
using (SPSite _site = new SPSite(spSiteURL))
                {
                    using (SPWeb _web = _site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                        {
                            _site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                            SPList _taskList = _web.Lists[spTaskListName];
                            SPListItem _taskItem = _taskList.GetItemById(8);
                            if (_taskItem != null)
                            {
                                _web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                                _taskItem["TaskOutcome"] = "Approved";
                                _taskItem["PercentComplete"] = "1";
                                _taskItem["Status"] = "Completed";
                                _taskItem.Update();
                                _web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Works for me but when a Workflow is awaiting on the task to be completed. We get an error from the Workflow (FormatException) it's trying to convert the String (TaskOutcome) into a Number.

Answer (score -1):

Answering very late. but following link explains how to approve SharePoint workflow 2013 using c# SSOM

https://timeofcode.wordpress.com/2018/10/13/pragmatically-approve-sharepoint-workflow-2013-c/